# Генетический алгоритм в задаче о 8 ферзях

Tags: python, алгоритм, numpy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import random


class Solver_8_queens:

    pop_size = 100
    board_width = 8
    cross_prob = 0.5
    mut_prob = 0.05

    def __init__(self, pop_size = 100, cross_prob=0.11, mut_prob=0.05):
        self.pop_size = pop_size
        self.cross_prob = cross_prob
        self.mut_prob = mut_prob

    def solve(self):
        population = self.generate_population()

        fit_func_in = self.fit_func(population)

        while np.max(fit_func_in) < 62:
            parent_pull = self.reproduction(fit_func_in, population)
            parent_pull = np.random.permutation(parent_pull)
            parent_fit_func = self.fit_func(parent_pull)
            crossingover_out = self.crossingover(parent_pull)
            self.mutation(crossingover_out)
            fit_func_cross = self.fit_func(crossingover_out)
            population = self.reduction(parent_pull, crossingover_out, parent_fit_func, fit_func_cross)
            fit_func_in = self.fit_func(population)

        print(population)

    def generate_population(self):
        population = np.zeros((self.pop_size, self.board_width), dtype=np.uint8)

        for hromosom in population:
            for position in range(len(hromosom)):
                hromosom[position] = random.randrange(0, self.board_width, 1)

        return population

    def fit_func(self, population):
        fit_func_result = np.zeros(self.pop_size, dtype = np.uint64)

        for index, hromosom in enumerate(population):
            #Вертикаль
            unique, counts = np.unique(hromosom, return_counts=True)
            unique_match, counts_match = np.unique(counts, return_counts=True)
            fit_func_result[index] += counts_match[0]

            # Диагонали
            for x in range(0,len(hromosom)):
                for y in range(0, len(hromosom)):
                    if int(abs(x - y)) != int(abs(hromosom[x] - hromosom[y])):
                        fit_func_result[index] += 1

        return fit_func_result

    def reproduction(self, fit_func, population):
        func_p = np.zeros(len(population), dtype = np.uint8)
        parent_pull = np.zeros((len(population), self.board_width), dtype=np.uint8)

        for index, hromosom in enumerate(fit_func):
            func_p[index] = round(fit_func[index] / np.sum(fit_func) * 100)

        wheel = []

        for x in range(0, len(population)):
            for _ in range(0, func_p[x]):
                wheel.append(x)

        for x in range(0, len(population)):
            parent_pull[x] = population[wheel[random.randrange(0, len(wheel), 1)]]

        return parent_pull

    def crossingover(self, parent_pull):
        crossingover_out = np.zeros((len(parent_pull), self.board_width), dtype=np.uint8)

        for x in range(0, int(self.pop_size/ 2)):
            if random.randrange(0, 100, 1) < self.cross_prob * 100:
                first_parent = parent_pull[x]
                second_parent = parent_pull[int(self.pop_size/ 2 - 1 - x)]

                k_point = random.randrange(1, self.board_width - 1, 1)

                crossingover_out[x] = np.concatenate((first_parent[:k_point], second_parent[k_point:]))
                crossingover_out[int(self.pop_size/ 2 - 1 - x)] = np.concatenate((second_parent[:k_point], first_parent[k_point:]))

        return crossingover_out

    def mutation(self, crossingover_out):
        for hromosom in crossingover_out:
            if random.randrange(0, 100, 1) < self.mut_prob * 100:
                hromosom[random.randrange(0, self.board_width, 1)] = random.randrange(0, self.board_width, 1)

    def reduction(self, population, crossingover_out, fit_func_in, fit_func_cross):
        full_hromosoms = np.vstack((population,crossingover_out))
        full_func_val = np.concatenate((fit_func_in, fit_func_cross))
        full_hromosoms = full_hromosoms[full_func_val.argsort()]
        return full_hromosoms[len(population):]
```

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Это реализация генетического алгоритма для задачи о 8 ферзях. Для его выполнения необходимо, чтобы значение функции было максимально (64), однако в 99% случаях выполнение приходится прерывать досрочно (10 минут выполняется, результата нет). Примечательно, что значения 62 он достигает за секунды (2 балла недобирает, т.к. 2 случая, когда фигуры под боем). Буду благодарен, если вы укажете на ошибку(Предполагаю, что проблема в fit_func при проверке диагоналей).

Comment: во-первых реализация `fit_func()`действительно сомнительна и стоит переписать её в очевидном виде... по крайней мере для примера... и лучше будет,если она будет принимать одну особь... во-вторых, у меня впечатление, что популяция вырождается: после 1000 итераций она состоит из одинаковых членов... думаю стоит добавить требование уникальности каждой особи... В-третьих, задача ИМХО не очень подходит для генетического решения: существует уж очень много локальных максимумов, в которых и происходит зацикливание...

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм допускает несложную и очень быструю рекурсивную реализацию (C#):

```
    public static void QPlus(List<string> result, string q)
    {
        bool ok;
        int i, n = q.Length, qn; 

        if (q.Length == 8)
        {
            result.Add(q);
            return;
        }
        for (qn = 1; qn < 9; qn++)
            if (q.IndexOf(qn + "") < 0)
            {
                for(ok = true, i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    if (((int)q[i] - 48 == qn - n + i) || 
                        ((int)q[i] - 48 == qn + n - i))
                    {
                        ok = false;
                        break;
                    }
                if (ok)
                        QPlus(result, q + qn);
            }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {
        int i = 1;
        string q8 = "";
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        QPlus(result, q8);
        foreach (string r in result)
            Console.Write("a{0}b{1}c{2}d{3}e{4}f{5}g{6}h{7}{8}", 
                r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], 
                (i++ % 4 == 0) ? "\n" : "  ");
    }
```

Результат:

```
a1b5c8d6e3f7g2h4  a1b6c8d3e7f4g2h5  a1b7c4d6e8f2g5h3  a1b7c5d8e2f4g6h3
a2b4c6d8e3f1g7h5  a2b5c7d1e3f8g6h4  a2b5c7d4e1f8g6h3  a2b6c1d7e4f8g3h5
a2b6c8d3e1f4g7h5  a2b7c3d6e8f5g1h4  a2b7c5d8e1f4g6h3  a2b8c6d1e3f5g7h4
a3b1c7d5e8f2g4h6  a3b5c2d8e1f7g4h6  a3b5c2d8e6f4g7h1  a3b5c7d1e4f2g8h6
a3b5c8d4e1f7g2h6  a3b6c2d5e8f1g7h4  a3b6c2d7e1f4g8h5  a3b6c2d7e5f1g8h4
a3b6c4d1e8f5g7h2  a3b6c4d2e8f5g7h1  a3b6c8d1e4f7g5h2  a3b6c8d1e5f7g2h4
a3b6c8d2e4f1g7h5  a3b7c2d8e5f1g4h6  a3b7c2d8e6f4g1h5  a3b8c4d7e1f6g2h5
a4b1c5d8e2f7g3h6  a4b1c5d8e6f3g7h2  a4b2c5d8e6f1g3h7  a4b2c7d3e6f8g1h5
a4b2c7d3e6f8g5h1  a4b2c7d5e1f8g6h3  a4b2c8d5e7f1g3h6  a4b2c8d6e1f3g5h7
a4b6c1d5e2f8g3h7  a4b6c8d2e7f1g3h5  a4b6c8d3e1f7g5h2  a4b7c1d8e5f2g6h3
a4b7c3d8e2f5g1h6  a4b7c5d2e6f1g3h8  a4b7c5d3e1f6g8h2  a4b8c1d3e6f2g7h5
a4b8c1d5e7f2g6h3  a4b8c5d3e1f7g2h6  a5b1c4d6e8f2g7h3  a5b1c8d4e2f7g3h6
a5b1c8d6e3f7g2h4  a5b2c4d6e8f3g1h7  a5b2c4d7e3f8g6h1  a5b2c6d1e7f4g8h3
a5b2c8d1e4f7g3h6  a5b3c1d6e8f2g4h7  a5b3c1d7e2f8g6h4  a5b3c8d4e7f1g6h2
a5b7c1d3e8f6g4h2  a5b7c1d4e2f8g6h3  a5b7c2d4e8f1g3h6  a5b7c2d6e3f1g4h8
a5b7c2d6e3f1g8h4  a5b7c4d1e3f8g6h2  a5b8c4d1e3f6g2h7  a5b8c4d1e7f2g6h3
a6b1c5d2e8f3g7h4  a6b2c7d1e3f5g8h4  a6b2c7d1e4f8g5h3  a6b3c1d7e5f8g2h4
a6b3c1d8e4f2g7h5  a6b3c1d8e5f2g4h7  a6b3c5d7e1f4g2h8  a6b3c5d8e1f4g2h7
a6b3c7d2e4f8g1h5  a6b3c7d2e8f5g1h4  a6b3c7d4e1f8g2h5  a6b4c1d5e8f2g7h3
a6b4c2d8e5f7g1h3  a6b4c7d1e3f5g2h8  a6b4c7d1e8f2g5h3  a6b8c2d4e1f7g5h3
a7b1c3d8e6f4g2h5  a7b2c4d1e8f5g3h6  a7b2c6d3e1f4g8h5  a7b3c1d6e8f5g2h4
a7b3c8d2e5f1g6h4  a7b4c2d5e8f1g3h6  a7b4c2d8e6f1g3h5  a7b5c3d1e6f8g2h4
a8b2c4d1e7f5g3h6  a8b2c5d3e1f7g4h6  a8b3c1d6e2f5g7h4  a8b4c1d3e6f2g7h5
```

А генетическая реализация работает, как ей велено:

```
        while np.max(fit_func_in) < 62:
```

И в то же время есть сильные сомнения по поводу параметра `mut_prob = 0.05`, который в двоичной системе счисления будет задан приближённо (по недостатку).

Comment: Требовалась конкретная реализация через генетический алгоритм, и порог 62 поставлен, дабы цикл мог завершиться (64 бесконечно считал)

Comment: @Welaury Указал ещё одно сомнительное место